# One box leaning against another box

Tags: geometry

Assuming the distance between A and B is 1.5 inch , what would be the distance of C from the ground?

[image: Click here for the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label the touching point $D$. Now $AB$ is $\frac 32$, $BD$ is $2=\frac 42$, so $AD$ is $\frac 52$.

Extend the  box slope down to the left of $C$ to the floor and label this point $E$. The triangle form below the left-hand box is congruent to $\triangle ABD$ so $CE=4+\frac 32 = \frac {11}2$.

Label th bottom of the vertical from $C$ as point $F$. Then $\triangle CEF$ is similar to $\triangle ABD$ and we can scale to get $CF = 2\times\frac {11}{5} = \frac {22}{5} = \fbox{4.4} $

Answer (score 0):

The distance from $C$ to ground is $AC\sin(\alpha+\beta)$, where $\tan\alpha={2\over1.5}={4\over3}$ and $\tan\beta={2\over4}={1\over2}$. By tangent addition formula we then get:
$$
\tan(\alpha+\beta)={4/3+1/2\over1-(4/3)(1/2)}={11\over2}
$$
so that
$$
\sin(\alpha+\beta)={\tan(\alpha+\beta)\over1+\tan^2(\alpha+\beta)}=
{11\over5\sqrt5}
$$
and
$$
\hbox{height}=AC\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sqrt{20}\cdot{11\over5\sqrt5}=
{22\over5}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $CD$ the required distance, $M$ the intersection between $CD$ and $AE=4$ (the side of the sloping triangles) and finally $T$, the touching point between the triangles.

We have: $AT=\sqrt{1.5^2+4}=2,5$.

The triangles $\triangle ABT$ and $\triangle CEM$ are similar so:
 $$AB:AT=CE:CM\longrightarrow1,5:2,5=2:CM,$$ hence $CM={10\over3}$ and applying the Pythagora's theorem to $\triangle CEM$ we get $$EM=\sqrt{\left({10\over3}\right)^2-4}={8\over3},$$ thus $AM=4-{8\over3}={4\over3}$. Now we see that $\triangle ADM$ and $\triangle CEM$ are similar as well, so it holds:$AM:MD=CM:EM\longrightarrow {4\over3}:MD={10\over3}:{8\over3}$ and $MD={16\over15}$.

$CD=CM+MD={10\over3}+{16\over15}={66\over15}={22\over5}$.